# Google Analytics custom variables usage

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am a newbie to GA. I am not sure whether GA is the right fit for the reports i m looking for. Kindly help

**My situation is:**

**I have a ajax form with submit and skip buttons for each question.**

**I need to track who all skipped or answered along with their user_id, question_id, campaign_id and category_id**

**And I should be able to retrieve the users who answered/skipped a particular campaign/question/category**

I tried using custom variables like:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'skip', 'yes', 1])
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Campaign', campaign_id, 1])
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'Engagement', question_id, 1])
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'Property', category_id, 1])
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'User', user_id, 1])
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'])
```

How do i get all the skipped users for a particular campaign or a question from this?

Does GA fit my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a violation of [Google Analytics terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html). See number 7 PRIVACY.

> 7.PRIVACY . You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track or collect personally identifiable information of Internet users, nor will You (or will You allow any third party to) associate any data gathered from Your website(s) (or such third parties' website(s)) with any personally identifying information from any source as part of Your use (or such third parties' use) of the Service. You will have and abide by an appropriate privacy policy and will comply with all applicable laws relating to the collection of information from visitors to Your websites. You must post a privacy policy and that policy must provide notice of your use of a cookie that collects anonymous traffic data.

And

> While the username or user ID is not directly PII, if it is used to tie to a person from a backend system…that’s a violation of the Terms of Service.

Google Analytics is not the tool to use for this type of tracking. As @Juhana said, a custom backend solution that is hosted on your own servers is the better way to go.

Comment: The terms of service have now changed to "You will not ... pass information to Google that Google could use or recognize as personally identifiable information." and the sentence about user ID is deleted. This suggests that since Google doesn't can't identify the user from the user ID then Google don't care if your store it. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

No. While it *might* be possible to accomplish this with Google Analytics, it's mainly meant to be a statistical tool so you're better off tracking the users on your own server or using some other service.

The main problem is that some users block or opt out of Google Analytics so you won't be able to get reliable information through it.

Comment: Any heads-up on how to accomplish this with google analytics?